# R- check unique values by all members in group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data like this:

```r
taxes_sol <- structure(list(type_tax = c(
  "good1", "good2", "good1", "good2",
  "good1", "good2", "good1", "good2",
  "good1", "good2", "good1", "good2"
), sol = c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x5", "x5", "x6", "x6"
), tax = c("0.11", "0.16", "0.09", "0.15", "0.11", "0.17",
  "0.09", "0.15", "0.21", "0.33", "0.11", "0.16"
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to keep the solutions where the taxes are different. In this case it would be to keep only the solutions: "x1", "x2", "x3" and "x5".

So I tried to do it with `distintc()` and grouping by type_tax and tax:

```r
taxes_sol %>% 
  distinct(type_tax, tax, .keep_all = T)
```

But that doesn’t return the good1 for "x3" solution.

Comment: It's correct that it doesn't return `good1` for `x3`, since its `tax` value is 0.11 and there is already a `tax` value of 0.11 and `good1` for `x1`

Answer (score 3):

An option with `duplicated`

```
library(dplyr)
taxes_sol %>% 
   mutate(flag = !duplicated(tax)) %>%
   group_by(sol) %>% 
   filter(any(flag)) %>% 
   select(-flag)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   sol [4]
#  type_tax sol   tax  
#  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#1 good1    x1    0.11 
#2 good2    x1    0.16 
#3 good1    x2    0.09 
#4 good2    x2    0.15 
#5 good1    x3    0.11 
#6 good2    x3    0.17 
#7 good1    x5    0.21 
#8 good2    x5    0.33
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% if this gives you what you are looking for. Using `dplyr`:

```r
taxes_sol %>%
  group_by(type_tax, tax) %>%
  mutate(counter = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(sol) %>%
  filter(any(counter == 1)) %>%
  select(-counter)
```

gives you

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   sol [4]
  type_tax sol   tax  
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 good1    x1    0.11 
2 good2    x1    0.16 
3 good1    x2    0.09 
4 good2    x2    0.15 
5 good1    x3    0.11 
6 good2    x3    0.17 
7 good1    x5    0.21 
8 good2    x5    0.33
```

Answer (score 2):

`distinct()` will not compare groups to each other, it will only compare individual columns. One way to compare groups is to first widen your data and then compare column values that define the group. After this, you can lengthen your data to get it into its original form:

```
taxes_sol %>% pivot_wider(
    names_from=type_tax,
    values_from=tax
) %>% distinct(
    good1,
    good2,
    .keep_all=T
) %>% pivot_longer(
    -sol,
    names_to="type_tax", values_to="tax"
)
```

`pivot_wider` does this to your data

```
  sol   good1 good2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x1    0.11  0.16 
2 x2    0.09  0.15 
3 x3    0.11  0.17 
4 x4    0.09  0.15 
5 x5    0.21  0.33 
6 x6    0.11  0.16
```

Your final answer looks like this

```
  sol   type_tax tax  
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1 x1    good1    0.11 
2 x1    good2    0.16 
3 x2    good1    0.09 
4 x2    good2    0.15 
5 x3    good1    0.11 
6 x3    good2    0.17 
7 x5    good1    0.21 
8 x5    good2    0.33
```